# UIViewController inside UIView not getting rotation delegation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a UIViewController's view inside my UIScrollView subclass. The problem is my UIViewController is not getting the willRotate delegate called when I rotate the device. This is probably because UIView does not have a rotation delegate implemented in it. What is the best way to solve this?

Basically the structure is I have a MainViewController in which it has a UIScrollView. Inside this UIScrollView I have a subviews, which is the view of a bunch of UIViewControllers. The issue now is, it's not getting rotation calls when I rotate. One way to deal with this is to delegate from the MainViewController to those respective UIViewController. Is there a better/elegant way to solve this?

I am adding it as a subview from my UIScrollView not my MainViewController and you can't do UIViewControllers containment from a UIView. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Ensure that the property of the `MainViewController`'s view `.autoresizeSubviews` is set to `YES`.

Comment: If your using iOS 5 you should use the childViewController API and add all those view controllers as children of the scroll views view controller.  Then you can have the rotation methods, along with all the other appearance methods for free.

Comment: @Matt yes..I was aware of this.. but how do I add a view controller as a child view of the scroll view? You can't add a childViewController from a UIView right? A UIScrollView is a UIView not a UIViewController. I guess UIViewController containment only works for UIViewController to UIViewController and not UIView to UIViewController? Correct me if I am wrong at understanding this

Comment: If you have a developer license you can view this video: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=102 It is very informative.  Basically, you have a view hierarchy, and a view controller hierarchy.  You want to add the view controllers into the controller hierarchy and their views into the view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watch the video that I posted in my comment: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=102

Here is a short summary of view controller containment, which is the design you are looking for, not combining all your logic into one view controller or using delegation for something that is built into the SDK.

A view controller has a view and provides logic for that view and most likely some of it's subviews.

You might have a complex view hierarchy and complex logic for specific views in that hierarchy that warrant the view to have it's own view controller controlling it and it's subviews.

Say you have a MainViewController and it's view is a UIScrollView (or subclass).  Inside that scrollview, you might have an assortment of complex views that warrant their own controller, so you have a class, SubViewController that has the subview of the scrollview as it's view.

SubViewController needs to have rotation and appearance method callbacks working correctly in order to implement your logic for the the subview and handle layout changes.

```
    [mainViewControllerInstance addChildViewController:subViewControllerInstance];
```

But, wait.  The subview is still not in the view hierarchy.

```
    [mainViewControllerInstance.view addSubView:subViewControllerInstance.view];
```

You have successfully created a valid view controller hierarchy of two view controllers and set up the associated view hierarchy of their views.

You will now have the appropriate callbacks functioning, as MainViewController will forward them to SubViewController.

EDIT:

See the documentation for an over view of view controller containment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going against the [MVC pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html). You can't have a controller inside a view; instead you should have a controller that mediates the communictaion between the view and the user's input. In your case you could set the scrollview as `self.view` of the `MainViewController`, and then add the viewcontrollers views as subviews.

Comment: great idea.. however again.. I have a subclass of UIScrollView, inside this subclass is where I am adding the view controller's as subview.. should I just then delegate to the view controller to say to add the vc as a child when I add it from the scroll view?

Comment: I can move all the logic of the UIScrollView subclass I have into my MainViewController because now it's view is the UIScrollView, however I want to reuse this UIScrollView in some other UIViewController

Comment: I think you should not put the uiviewcontrollers views as subviews of the scrollviews, these are just views..you should have one controller that manages all the subviews.

Comment: well..what if I have to? then do the delegate? I mean it's a really long explanation if I have to explain this. I know the best way is just to have it as view's inside the scroll view.. but I really can't

Comment: yes could use delegation or just re-use it as UIViewController instead just a sublass of UIView. But i don't uderstand correctly what you're trying to resolve.